# SAP HANA and Python using hdbcli problem with dates

Tags: python, datetime, hana, sapb1

I'm using python to connect to SAP HANA, and I use hdbcli. I send a query like this `select * from oinv` and the dates are like this date `time.datetime(2023, 11, 22)` this is my first issue.

The second is when I send `select * from oinv where [DocEntry] = 2679420` says invalid column name, but it exists in that table.

Anyone can help me to make a query like this `select * from oinv where DocDate = '2024-01-10'`?

So I use `[]` or `""` or `''` inside the query and I get the same result
my problem is how can I put the database column name in a query from python and the other problem is how put the dates in the queries to filter results.

Thank you.